# Sub-bundles of globally generated vector bundles.

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Given a globally generated vector bundle $E$ on an algebraic variety $X$, let $F\subset E$ be a proper sub-bundle. Are there conditions on $E$, $F$ and $Q:=E/F$ that ensure that $F$ is globally generated as well?

Comment: The snake lemma shows that if the natural adjunction map $H^0(X,Q)\otimes{\cal O}_X\to Q$ is injective, then $F$ is globally generated.

Comment: That map is surely surjective since $Q$ is globally generated. Do you mean $Q\simeq\mathcal{O}_X^{\oplus rk Q}$? 

Comment: @ginevra86 : you are right; so what I am saying is that if $Q$ is a sum of trivial bundles, then $F$ is globally generated too - that is probably not very useful, sorry. Note that the snake lemma argument gives something a bit stronger: if the adjunction 
map $H^0(X,Q)\otimes{\cal O}_X\to Q$ is injective on the subsheaf 
$({\rm ker}(H^0(X,Q)\to H^1(F,X))\otimes{\cal O}_X$, then $F$ is globally generated.